# How can I share files in my server using python by web

Tags: python, web, download, upload

I wanna share my files to clients.
Files are created in my server everyday. (ex. 20210701_A, 20210702_A ....)
Client will download today's file.
I already made choosing right file using python code.

But How can my clients download files from their own web?
(If possible, I want using Python)

Comment: Most simple option: Go to the folder you want to share and run `python -m http.server 8000`. You will find more options in the docs of `http.server`.

Comment: client can't download `your file` from `his web` - you would have to upload file on `his web`. if it can gives you access by SSH of FTP to some folder then you could upload ti but he would need also some code which will create link to this file on his web page.

Comment: BTW: using `http.server` you can sever your local file by web - but usually Internet Providers blocks access to your servers - for security reason - and people from internet can't access it. Only people in local network can access it. I would need special methods to redirecting/tuneling it - ie. using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). It can be simpler to create own web page on external server - like [PythonAnywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/) - or upload on Google Drive or Microsoft One Drive and share link to this file.

Comment: BTW: client may put on his web page link to file on your server and when someone click it on his server then it will download it from your server. But if you don't have access to his web page code then only owner can add this link to his web page.